# Is there a way to add/inject a property to Vert.x request object?

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I'm wondering if Vert.x has an ability to add/inject a property to a request object like in Next.js.

Comment: what is your use-case?

Comment: To pass some values around for internal use in respect to that particular request. Anyway, I found the answer and I'll put it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer the Vert.x way.
Anyway, apparently I can pass any properties to `RoutingContext` object; instead of `request` object like Next.js.
i.e. `routingContext.put("prop name", "some value")`

This piece of data will be available in any handlers that receive the context down in your function chain.
To access it you can do `routingContext.get<T>("prop name")`

My use case is to store the timestamp of a request as soon as it comes then later used in some other function to store it as one of metrics.